# Transparent element in html

Tags: html, css

I want to make a button and next to it a div, but div should have relative position and be moved to the left, so this way it would overlap a button and it couldn't be clicked, so I wonder is there a way to do that? except putting a button into that div.

here is something what i'm trying to do:

```css
div {
  background-color:green;
  width:200px;
}
input:checked+div {
  background-color:salmon;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type=checkbox>
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:200px;position:relative;left:-30px;">
    <p>
    text
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

So i just need to make input here clickable

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: @mplungjan i posted the closest thing to what i need to do, cant post nothing more...

Comment: While posting your question you CLEARLY were prompted to also post code with your jsfiddle link, which you bypassed by posting a single `c` as code. This is NOT what you should to. Please refer to the help center, as suggested by @mplungjan and learn how to ask a proper question. Remember, you are here to get advice for free, so the least you can do is try to keep your questions to a certain standard.

Comment: do you want it to be clickable or visible too? Are you sure that you want the checkbox to be clickable through the div or you need the div to pass all the clicks to the checkbox? All this is doable, but you should specify the intention a bit. Actually, the title and the text of your question don't quite match.. please describe how the actual result is different from the desirable one

Answer (score 0):

Not a good way to solve it, but you could work with `position: relative; z-index: 1` on your button. I would consider creating a different structure altogether, since this is really ugly and unmanageable. See https://jsfiddle.net/w6ymq758/